# improving loop throw a schema on php

Tags: php, json, jsonschema

This is working, but feels really "dirty"

I have a schema json like:

```
[
  {
    "url": "http://www.google.com/api/updateVariable",
    "verb": "POST",
    "bodySchema": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "StoreId": {
          "sync": "True",
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "SKU": {
          "sync": "True",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "WareHouseId": {
          "sync": "False",
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "Stock": {
          "sync": "True",
          "type": "integer"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "StoreId",
        "SKU",
        "Stock"
      ]
    }
  },

  {
    "url": "http://www.google.com/api/insertVariable",
    "verb": "POST",
    "bodySchema": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "StoreId": {
          "sync": "True",
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "SKU": {
          "sync": "True",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "WareHouseId": {
          "sync": "False",
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "Description": {
          "sync": "True",
          "type": "integer"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "StoreId",
        "SKU",
        "Description"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

And I want to loop throw all the properties (once again, this is working)

```
    $result=json_decode($result, true);
    while($item = array_shift($result)){
        foreach ($item as $key => $value){
            if($key=="bodySchema"){
                foreach ($value as $key2 => $value3){
                    if($key2==properties)
                        var_dump($value3);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

What I would like to have is something like:

```
$result=json_decode($result, true);
foreach($result as $mydata){
     foreach($mydata->bodySchema->properties as $values){
          var_dump($values->value);
     }
}
```

is this possible?, I want to keep this code as clean and neat as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it the way you want.  You just have some syntax to cleanup to do.

In this example, `$result` is an associative array, so you can index into it just like any array.

```
$result = json_decode($result, true);
foreach ($result as $mydata) {
    foreach ($mydata["bodySchema"]["properties"] as $propertyName => $schema){
          var_dump([$propertyName, $schema]);
    }
}
```

If you prefer object syntax, drop the `true` from `json_decode`.

```
$result = json_decode($result);
foreach ($result as $mydata) {
    foreach ($mydata->bodySchema->properties as $propertyName => $schema){
          var_dump([$propertyName, $schema]);
    }
}
```